# MySQl: where comparing values

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table Test_Results

```
| ID | Test_ID | Device_OS| Status | Date     | Device_ID |
| 1  | 1       | Android  | passed | 2015/10  | 1         |
| 2  | 1       | Android  | failed | 2015/10  | 1         |
| 3  | 15      | iOS      | failed | 2015/11  | 2         |
| 4  | 20      | Android  | passed | 2015/11  | 1         |
| 5  | 27      | Android  | failed | 2015/11  | 1         |
| 6  | 10      | iOS      | failed | 2015/12  | 2         |
| 7  | 5       | Android  | passed | 2015/12  | 1         |
```

I need to select the tests that failed on Device with ID = 1, but passed on Device with ID =2.

So I need to compare values based on Device_ID, can you please direct me what to search on the Internet.

Comment: And what is your Problem?

Comment: I don't know how to build the query so far, it's not pure 'where' clause, I'm not sure how to perform the comparison.

Comment: Show the expected result

Comment: I forgot that its not related with php... sorry...

Comment: "tests that failed on Device with ID = 1, but passed on Device with ID =2" - your sample data doesn't include such a case, right? But it would if the Device_ID in the first row (ID=1) would be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both the conditions to be satisfied, then try this:

```
SELECT Test_ID
FROM Test_Results
WHERE Test_ID IN (SELECT Test_ID FROM Test_Results WHERE Device_ID = 1 AND Status LIKE 'failed')
AND Device_ID = 2 AND Status LIKE 'passed'
```

Comment: Thanks. IN clause is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Test_ID, COUNT(Test_ID) as TEST_COUNT from Test_Results 
where (Status='failed' AND Device_ID = 1) OR (Status='passed' AND Device_ID = 2)
group by Test_ID
Having TEST_COUNT>1
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make it in secure way....

```
            SELECT * 
            FROM Test_Results
            WHERE (`Device_ID` = 1 AND `Status` = 'passed') 
                  OR
                  (`Device_ID` = 2 AND `Status` = 'failed');
```

Hope will work perfectly...